# Visual Studio 2022 AssemblyInfo.cs missing

Tags: c#, .net, docker-compose, visual-studio-2022

Previously I used my project using visual studio 2019 with .net 3.1 through docker-compose it ran normally without problems, after I updated visual studio to version 2022, problems started to appear if I run docker-compose the error is as shown below (Could not find file ........\AssemblyInfo.cs)

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ3FA.png)

The file is not automatically created when run docker-compose, I have to rebuild/build the solution or rebuild/build each service/projects to work normally.
Is there any additional setup for visual studio 2022 so I don't have to rebuild/build a solution to generate that file?
TIA.

I've tried looking for the same case and solution on the internet but can't find it.

Comment: This is probably caused by a problem in your .csproj or .props files. Can you show the contents of one of the affected .csproj files?

Comment: A solution with 172 projects in it seems excessive to me - can you break-up the solution into smaller project groups?

Comment: @PMF here he is [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pBeWHxBK)

Comment: @codeit3003 Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74429011/edit) your question and include that, instead of referencing an external source.